# Coloring a column variable in a Data Frame and export it to Excel

Tags: r

Is it possible to colour a column variable, Expired in my Dataframe without having to convert it to a Datatable? If not, what does the error shown below means and how do I debug it?

My Dataframe

```
    Id  Name Membership
1 1001  John       Gold
2 1002  Neil       Gold
3 1002  Sam        Expired
4 1003  Tom        Silver
```

Current code

```
df <- datatable(df, rownames = FALSE) %>% formatStyle(columns = "Membership, background = 
      styleEqual(c("Expired"),c("Red")))
```

when I try to convert it back to a data frame back or export it to excel. I will come across this error

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors): cannot coerce class `c("datatables", "htmlwidget")' to a data.frame
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `openxlsx` library. There's a lot of steps for even simple formatting, but the advantage is you can do most of the same formatting rules you would do in Excel. For this method, you wouldn't convert to a `datatable`, just keep your data in a `dataframe`, insert it into a `Workbook` object, apply formatting then `saveWorkbook()`.

```
library(openxlsx)
library(tidyverse)

df <- data_frame(Id = c(1001,1002,1002,1003),
                 Name = c('John','Neil','Sam','Tom'),
                 Membership = c('Gold','Gold','Expired','Silver'))

wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, 'Members')
writeData(wb, 'Members', df)
redStyle = createStyle(fontColour = '#FF0000')
conditionalFormatting(wb, 'Members', 
                      cols = 3,
                      rows = 1:5,
                      rule = '=="Expired"',
                      style = redStyle)

saveWorkbook(wb, 'export.xlsx', overwrite = TRUE)
```

If course, if the idea is to have formatted cells displayed in your R console, this won't work. If you're mostly interested in a formatted `.xlsx` output, this will do exactly what you need.